# Using RPCGen to understand RPC

Tags: c, rpc

I am trying to understand basics of RPC using RPCGen. I followed a basic tutorial and wrote the follwing myrpc.x file

```
program MESSAGEPROG {
    version EVALMESSAGEVERS {
        int EVALMESSAGE(string) = 1;
    } = 1;
} = 0x20000002;
```

I compile it by running

```
rpcgen -a -C myrpc.x
```

In the resulting server.c file, I added a printf statement as below

```
printf("Message is: %s,\n", *argp);
```

Then i run make -f Makefile.myrpc and start the server by running myrpc_server. Now when i run the client 'myrpc_client', I get the following message printed in the server

```
Message is: H���5�
```

Now my question is from where does this argument come from "H���5�" as this is not the argument which i am when running the client? Also can someone explain me how do i start running complex programs with rpcgen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The garbage value is from code on line 15 in client.c, where is uninitialized variable used as an argument for your rpc call. My version of rpc show an error:

> call failed: RPC: Can't encode arguments"

```
15     char * evalmessage_1_arg;
```

"How do I start running complex programs with rpc?" It' just on you. We cannot say when you need to use rpc. You probably have some reason for what you chose this implementation.

Some use case for rpc is thin client on slow computer, which needs some expensive computation. Client sends data to powerful server, that do the hard work and returns result.